# How I can tembed the flourish chart with parameter to the filter

Tags: embed

[image]

What option can help me use this filter with url to embeded.

I try these code:

```
<div class="flourish-embed flourish-map" data-src="visualisation/9083550?country=ANGOLA">
  <script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

I try url for embed:

```
https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/9083550/embed?auto=1&country=ANGOLA
```

or

```
https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/9083550/embed?auto=1&Country=ANGOLA
```

I try to found in the documentation for embeded, but doc is very small and empty.